# save transparent web images on linux mint

Tags: images

I have just installed Linux Mint (this is my first day using). I'm using Google chrome and search Google images for a transparent png, for example an icon with no background. I am right click saving as...

Here is a screen shot of what happens:

[image]

The images listed in the order of me saving (descending), numbered as seen (left to right):

3) A real png node-webkit icon with some transparent pixels for the background, when I open it I see no image only black in the image viewer.

2) A real github jpg with a white background. I wanted to see if saving any image was not working. I can see this fine in the image viewer

1) This is really a png with transparency, but when the dialogue came up to save it I chose to save as * all files, and renamed the extension myself to jpg then when I open it I see no image only black in the image viewer

4) A real png (from Google images someone else must of named it screen_shoot). This image differs from the other png in that it has no transparent pixels. I can see this fine in the image viewer

Why wont saving / viewing png images with transparency work?

Comment: This seems to be just a problem with displaying a thumbnail in this particular file manager (which is it?). Nothing to worry about. The image should be fine, saving a file from the web doesn't even care what's inside, it's just a slight inconvenience to not see the preview.

Comment: Cinnamon 64-bit An edition featuring the Cinnamon desktop

Comment: Use the browser to view the images. Some image viewers don't handle transparency correctly. When in doubt fire up the `gimp` and use that, transparency shuld be shown as a grey checkerboard.

Comment: Try to install `tumbler` package and reboot, it should improve thumbnail management.